# Auto complete of braces in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am wondering whether there is a method in emacs editor that while writing some codes (say in R or Latex) the obvious closing braces come automatically. Like if I use RStudio, the closing brace appears whenever I write an open brace. This feature is available in Kile too (talking about using Latex). By default this feature is not available in emacs (with ESS). Is there some way I can activate this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are several solutions. One is here:

https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens